# Hiding backpack waistband

Tags: gear, backpacks

I just got this backpack but noticed that the waistband can't be concealed when not being used. It is the one with a large buckle in the bottom of the picture below.

[image]

Since I plan to use it snowboarding, dangling straps can be a hazard, particularly when getting off the lift etc. I'm looking for an idea for how to hide them. I think it would be ideal if they came out of pockets with zippers so they can be tucked inside the pack when not utilized. If not, do you think they sell packs that have that feature?

Comment: Are you planning to not use the waist strap at all, or when you do use it the straps are too long and dangle?

Comment: Any reason to not just wear the waist strap? I did so when snowboarding, and I liked the additional stability it gave the pack on my back...

Comment: See also [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14576/is-it-unsafe-to-ride-the-chair-lift-with-a-backpack).

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell from the picture whether this would work with that pack, but with some of mine I run the hip belt round the pack rather than round me, before fastening it round the back. If you're worried about it snagging after that, you might want to put an elasticated rain cover over the top.

I've seen packs with covers for *all* the straps, but not just for the belt. Actually I've got two that cover the straps - they convert into bike panniers (one doesn't have a belt at all). But these tend to be not very good as general backpacks. Either they're a compromise like my panniers, or they're large travel backpacks that you can treat like a suitcase.

If you can pull it tight enough that the belt buckle is in the small of your back, maybe you could pad it enough to be comfortable.